# Dask distributed library giving serialization error

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I have initialized the cluster with 10 workers and 4 thread per worker and I have 12 core laptop where I am running this.

```
    cluster = makeIndividualDashboard.LocalCluster(n_workers=10, threads_per_worker=4)
    client = makeIndividualDashboard.Client()
    runOna(client)
    client.shutdown()
```

now below is the code where i am doing the cluster computing.

```
    st = settings.as_dict()
    new_settings = namedtuple("Settings", st.keys())(*st.values())
    to_process = []
    client.cluster.scale(10)
    if mongoConnection:
        mongo_c = True
    else:
        mongo_c = None
    future = client.scatter([net, new_settings, avgNodesConnected, kcoreByGroup, averageTeamDensity,
                             edgesInByAttributeTableMeans, edgesInByAttributeTable, crossTeamTiesTable,
                             descendentLookup, groupDegreeTable, respondentDegreeTable, degreeTable,
                             orgTeamTree, teamMembership, graphId, selectionRange, criteria,
                             onlyForNodes, hashIds, useEnvironment, rollupToLeaders, averageTeamSize,
                             meanCrossInTiesPct, meanCrossOutTiesPct, meanCrossAllTiesPct, mongo_c])
    for node in nodes:
        if FILTER_FOR_USER == None or node == FILTER_FOR_USER:
            to_process.append(dask.delayed(run_me)(node, *future))

    dask.compute(*to_process)
```

yes, this looks bit messy because run_me is a very big function as of now I can not modularize better in the future maybe I will. the issue is this work fine if I have only **5** workers or less but as soon I increase the number of workers this gives me serialization error.

```
distributed.protocol.core - CRITICAL - Failed to Serialize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/omtripa/anaconda3/envs/ONA-Transformation/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/protocol/core.py", line 44, in dumps
    for key, value in data.items()
  File "/Users/omtripa/anaconda3/envs/ONA-Transformation/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/protocol/core.py", line 45, in <dictcomp>
    if type(value) is Serialize
  File "/Users/omtripa/anaconda3/envs/ONA-Transformation/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/protocol/serialize.py", line 210, in serialize
TypeError: ('Could not serialize object of type float64.', '0.68')
distributed.comm.utils - ERROR - ('Could not serialize object of type float64.', '0.68')
```

Again this is very weird because if i run this in the Linux server which has 35 core and I put numbers of workers 30 works fine not sure what is the issue. is this specific to my local ?? i can look for serialization issue but why this works with 5 workers only ??

Thanks in Advance for any help.

Comment: There are many things in your code that are not defined here, so we are not able to reproduce your problem. That relegates us to pure guessing...

Comment: sorry as of now its difficult for me to give a minimal reproducible example i will try to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says that there is some object that you're trying to send to a worker that is not serializable.  The type is a `float64`, which is maybe a numpy.float64 object?  I don't really know given what you've said.  I've verified that Dask moves around Numpy float64 objects just fine

```
In [1]: from dask.distributed import Client                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [2]: client = Client()                                                                                                                                                                                                           

In [3]: import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                                                          

In [4]: x = np.float64(1)                                                                                                                                                                                                           

In [5]: future = client.scatter(x)                                                                                                                                                                                                  

In [6]: future.result()                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[6]: 1.0
```

I encourage you to provide an MCVE.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: thanks for your answer, yes i got the error and yes its numpy.float64 but the issue is why this work if i have only 5 workers. and sorry as of now its difficult for me to give minimal reproducible example.

Comment: i have one doubt though what is client.cluster.scale(10) exactly do. does it increase the number of distributer ??